# Why does 「...ことと思います」mean "I hope that ..."?

Tags: grammar, nuances, greetings, conversations

In [this Hinative question](https://hinative.com/questions/18439015/) about the best way to translate the simple small-talk phrase "I hope you had a good weekend", two native Japanese speakers both reply with a "...ことと思います" pattern: 「いい週末だったことと思います。」「よい週末を過ごしたことと思います。」 (Although they also note that a question-form 「いい週末でしたか」 would also be natural.)

I can't find anything about a "...ことと思います" grammar pattern, and I'm racking my brain trying figure out why this pattern would equate to "I hope that..." in English. What does this pattern actually express? How else might I use it in Japanese?

Comment: There is no good way to “hope” that something already happened in Japanese.

Comment: I wonder if it's roughly equivalent to "I trust that you had a good weekend"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ことと思います is one of the polite variants of ことだろう/ことでしょう. よい週末を過ごしたことでしょう is equally fine in this context.

This type of こと adds an exclamatory feeling and/or the level of certainty to an inferential sentence. It's hard to translate this, but "(for) sure", "naturally" or "indeed" may have a similar connotation in English.

> それはとても残念だっただろう。
> それはとても残念だった**こと**だろう。
> それはとても残念だった**こと**と思います。
> (It) must have been very disappointing.
>
> 明日には東京に着いているでしょう。
> 明日には東京に着いている**こと**でしょう。
> 明日には東京に着いている**こと**と思います。
> (We) will arrive in Tokyo tomorrow.
>
> お疲れでしょう。
> お疲れの**こと**でしょう。
> お疲れの**こと**(だ)と思います。
> You must be tired.
>
> お気づきでしょうが、…
> お気づきの**こと**でしょうが、…
> お気づきの**こと**と思いますが、…
> You probably have noticed this, but ...

In particular, I feel this type of こと is common in the context of inferring someone's feelings or situation.

こと is also used in an exclamatory sentence like this:

> なんと素晴らしいのでしょう。
> なんと素晴らしい**こと**でしょう。
> なんと素晴らしい**こと**だ！
> なんと素晴らしい**こと**！ (rare, feminine)
> How wonderful!

As pointed out as a comment, expressions directly related to hoping do not work well in this context.